# How to get the max index of distinct groups of integers in a python list

Tags: python

Example:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

In this case I need:

1. 1st `'0'` group = index: 0-4 , length : 5
2. 1st `'1'` group = index: 5-6 ,    length : 2
3. 2nd `'0'` group = index: 7 , length : 1
4. **2nd `'1'` group = index: 8-17 , length : 10** <---- NEED THIS the index of max length of `'1'`s
5. 3rd `'0`' group = index: 18 - 22 , length : 5

Comment: What have you tried so far? Generally on StackOverflow you should post what code you currently have and what is going wrong with it.

Comment: What is length here? Length on group 4 says 10 but you say it should be max of 1.

Comment: @Jab I think "max length of 1" was supposed to mean "maximum length of a sequence of consecutive 1 values".

Comment: @Jab and Karl:  yes I meant the max length of the sequence '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate using the following function:

```
def count_through_a_list(x):
  """
  returns all distinct continuous groups of values in a list
  output is in the form of records
  """

  # Initialize these values
  group_start = 0
  group_count = 1
  prev = x[0]
  groups = []

  for i,n in enumerate(x):

    # if n is not the same as the previous value OR i is the last index
    if n!=prev or i == len(x)-1:
      groups.append({'start':group_start, 'end':i-1, 'value':prev, 'length':i-group_start, 'group_counter':group_count})
      # Reset the appropriate values
      group_count+=1
      group_start = i
      prev = n

  return groups

groups = count_through_a_list(x)

pd.DataFrame(groups, columns=['start','end','value', 'length', 'group_counter'])

    start   end value   length  group_counter
0   0   4   0   5   1
1   5   6   1   2   2
2   7   7   0   1   3
3   8   17  1   10  4
4   18  21  0   4   5
```

Comment: NameError: name 'get_all_groups' is not defined .. think you forgot to rename the function or the call of the function

Comment: Ah. Error when I renamed the function. Should work now.

Comment: it's a good answer...but funny how a solution gets accepted and called "on point" when it doesn't work at the time XD

Comment: When you create the `df` just use `columns= groups[0].keys()` no need to have the names rewritten

Comment: Note the solution is the design and code of an approach. Typos happen and can be considered beyond a "solution"

Comment: @Jab for the specific ordering of them.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `itertools.groupby`. With this you can get a list of lists by each grouping of integers in the original dataset.

```
>>> data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [list(group) for _, group in itertools.groupby(data)]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0,0, 0]]
```

Or to get indexes, you can also do this in one line using `itertools.groupby and .islice` and `operator.itemgetter`

```
>>> [sorted(set(itemgetter(0, -1)([i[0] for i in g))) for _, g in groupby(enumerate(data), key=itemgetter(1))]
[[0, 4], [5, 6], [7], [8, 17], [18, 22]]
```

Or to get the starting or ending indexes, use this: *(notice `min` and `max` determine the start or end index)*

```
>>> [min(i[0] for i in group) for _, group in groupby(data)]
[0, 5, 7, 8, 18]
>>> [max(i[0] for i in group) for _, group in groupby(data)]
[4, 6, 7, 17, 22]
```

And to get the starting index of the largest group use:

```
>>> max(([next(group)[0], sum(1 for _ in group)] for _, group in groupby(enumerate(data), key=itemgetter(1))), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
8
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard library provides `itertools.groupby` for this purpose. It's a bit tricky to use, because it does a lot of work:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> groupby(data)
<itertools.groupby object at 0x0000015AB6EB3C78>
```

Hmm. It doesn't seem very useful yet. But we look at the documentation and see that it's a generator, so let's try expanding it into a list:

```
>>> list(groupby(data))
[(0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000015AB6EC2BA8>), (1, <itertools._grouper
 object at 0x0000015AB6ED82B0>), (0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000015AB6E
D8518>), (1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000015AB6EFE780>), (0, <itertools.
_grouper object at 0x0000015AB6F028D0>)]
```

The 0 and 1 values in here correspond to the 0s and 1s in the original `data`, but we still have these other objects. Those are also generators:

```
>>> [(value, list(grouper)) for value, grouper in groupby(data)]
[(0, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), (1, [1, 1]), (0, [0]), (1, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1]), (0, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Now we can see what's going on: the grouper objects generate chunks from the list.

So all we need to do is check the `len` of those lists and get the maximum value. We fix the comprehension so that we ignore the `value` and get the `len` of each `grouper`, and feed the results to the built-in `max` instead of making a list:

```
>>> max(len(list(grouper)) for value, grouper in groupby(data))
10
```

Comment: Thanks @Karl ! So I do get the value of MAX length of the sequences (0s and 1s). But I essentially need the index too. That would be 8-17 in this case.

Comment: In that case you might have to do it manually. Think about how you would solve it with paper and pencil, looking at each element one at a time. What information would you have to remember during the process?

Comment: Well (a) I could iterate over the list (b) whenever I encounter 1, I start count and start index (c) when there's no 1 anymore record end index (d) repeat and check if count value increased (e) max of the corresponding count's start and end gives me the index.
But this is of course not efficient!

Comment: It's hard work, but the efficiency is fine. You only need to look at each element once, right? And you won't be able to do any better than that, clearly. The itertools solution has to look at every element, too, just in a more hidden way.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it another way without itertools:

```
j=0
for i,val in enumerate(data):
    if i == 0:
        out=[[val]]
    if val == data[i-1]:
        out[j] += [val]
    else:
        j+=1
        out += [[val]]
```

output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

now, make a dict with the unique values and the lengths of the sublists for each value:

```
counts = {}
for o in out:
    if o[0] not in counts.keys():
        counts[o[0]] = [len(o)]
    else:
        counts[o[0]] += [len(o)]
```

output:

```
{0: [6, 1, 5], 1: [2, 10]}
```

now get the max length of the sequences with the value you are after, in your case it's 1:

```
max(counts[1])
```

output:

```
10
```

EDIT : to also get the indices of this specific sequence you can do this:

```
id0 = 0
for o in out:
    if o[0] != 1 or len(o) != max(counts[1]):
        id0 += len(o)
    if o[0] == 1 and len(o) == max(counts[1]):
        id0 -= 1
        break

id1 = id0 + max(counts[1]) - 1
print(max(counts[1]), id0, id1)
```

output:

```
10 8 17
```

it isnt the prettiest...but it works :)

Comment: sorry the wording and the comments are confusing, is it the length or the index you are after?

Comment: i need the "index" as specified in question and comments. Thanku for the solution. I'm using it to mark a certain core region in an image based on parameters using which I've mapped already as '0's and '1's.